# How to define custom mysql function in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to sort some resources with mysql. It requires of me to handle it like this

```
scope :sorted_by_source, -> { select("set_name(source) as source_name").order("source_name ASC") }
```

So as you can see function set_name is gonna return something which will later allow me to do order by. However i dont know how to define this function in Rails? Where should i put it, whats the syntax? (I'm gonna need switch statement)

Using Rails 3 and MySql

Comment: Why don't you just order by source?  I just don't understand why you're trying to do this

Comment: its not in the database, trust me its kinda complicated and i really need this custom function

Comment: If it's not in the database you're going to need to sort it in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding migration and executing in up some sql to setup function

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
   CREATE FUNCTION ...
  SQL
end

def down
  execute <<-SQL
    DROP FUNCTION ...
  SQL
end
```